# Determine whether function parameter is a function

Tags: c++, templates

How can I determine whether a function's parameter *type* is a **function**? I'm implementing a class called `Queue` which receives a single parameter. If the parameter is a function, it stores the function.

Here is the code:

```cpp
template <class Type, typename Data>
class Queue {
    public:
        void Enqueue (Data& data) {
            if (typeid(data).name() == int) {
                intVector.push_back(data);
                order.push_back("int");
            }
            else if (typeid(data).name() == bool) {
                boolVector.push_back(data);
                order.push_back("bool");
            }
            else if (typeid().name() == string) {  
              stringVector.push_back(data);
              order.push_back("string");
            }
            // This will continue for:
            // - double
            // - char
            // - function
        }

        auto Dequeue () {
            auto temp;
            switch (order.begin()) {
                case "int":
                    temp = intVector.begin();
                    intVector.erase(intVector.begin());
                    order.erase(order.begin());
                    return temp;
                // This will continue for:
                // - "string"
                // - "bool"
                // - "char"
                // - "double"
                // - "function"
                default:
                    cout << "An Error occurred while trying to Enqueue." << endl;
                    cout << "\tAddress: " << this << endl;
            }
        }

        auto Start () {
            // This function will run all of the processes...
        }
        Queue (Data& data) {
            if (typeid(Type).name() == int) {
                // Pseodo-code:
                // if (data.type == function) {
                //     Enqueue (data);
                // }
            }
        }
}
```

It can be initialised:

```cpp
Queue queue1 = new Queue <int> (func ()); // func () is a function.
Queue queue2 = new Queue <int> (var);     // var is a variable.
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function

Comment: But take care, everything the compiler sees in the other parts of the branch must be still compilable, even if it's no function.

Comment: Thank you. So do you mean that I must make sure that I use everything, like if it is an Integer, I must manipulate it as well? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: The usual pattern is to provide two versions of your template class implementation and enable these mutually using [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖthanks. I understand now.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you could consider replacing `if (typeid(Type).name() == int)` with `if (std::is_same<Type, int)::value)` as it is, arguably, a little more elegant.  Requires `#include <type_traits>`.  But why are you testing for that sort of thing in your template in the first place?  It's not really in the spirit of things.

Comment: @PaulSanders Queues are *Data Structures* that perform tasks in a Queue form. Integers and basic types are stored, and they get returned in the same way. Function are stored but they get executed as they are returned. This allows quick exact timing execution.

Comment: Also, in the source code, there is a `Step` variable that allows  an object to be returned every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but why are you testing _`Type`_?

Comment: @PaulSanders The reason is `type`Storage. So if it is an int, it will be `int`Storage

Comment: I think you should show us (in your question) the entire template.  Cleaner solutions may be possible.

Comment: Note that `new` returns a pointer and that you are executing your function `func ()` instead of passing it as an argument.

Comment: I have extended the code @PaulSanders

Comment: @KillzoneKid how can I make it so that the function is just passed?

Comment: @EdwinPratt without `()` just the name

Comment: Like `func`? @KillzoneKid

Comment: @Edwin Re-posting your full template: let me see what I can do with the parts I'm competent to comment on. L8R, hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my.  This is a bit of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Anyway, after messing around with `std::enable_if` for a bit (which was kinda fun), I realised that the whole thing can be boiled down to this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void call_if_function (void (* f) ()) { f (); }
void call_if_function (std::function <void ()> f) { f (); }
void call_if_function (std::any x) { (void) x; }

template <class T>
class Queue
{
    public:
        void Enqueue (const T& data)
        {
//          std::cout << "Enqueueing " << data << "\n";
            v.push_back (data);
        }

        T Dequeue ()
        {
            T ret = v.front ();
//          std::cout << "Dequeueing " << ret << "\n";
            v.erase (v.begin ());
            call_if_function (ret);
            return ret;
        }

    private:
        std::vector <T> v;
};
```

And, if I understand the OP's problem right, that is all all you need.

Test program:

```
void foo () { std::cout << "foo () called\n"; }
void bar (int x, int y) { std::cout << "bar () called, x = " << x << ", y = " << y << "\n"; }

int main ()
{
    // Queue of int's
    Queue <int> int_q;
    int_q.Enqueue (42);
    auto i = int_q.Dequeue ();
    std::cout << "int_q.Dequeue () returned " << i << "\n\n";

    // Queue of strings
    Queue <std::string> string_q;
    string_q.Enqueue ("Hello world");
    auto s = string_q.Dequeue ();
    std::cout << "string_q.Dequeue () returned " << s << "\n\n";

    // Call function with no parameters    
    Queue <void (*)()> func_q;
    func_q.Enqueue (foo);
    auto f = func_q.Dequeue ();
    std::cout << "func_q.Dequeue () returned " << (void *) f << "\n";
    f ();

    // Call function with arbitrary parameters
    Queue <std::function <void ()>> func_qp;
    func_qp.Enqueue ([] () { bar (21, 99); });
    auto fp = func_qp.Dequeue ();
    fp ();
}
```

Output:

```
int_q.Dequeue () returned 42

string_q.Dequeue () returned Hello world

foo () called
func_q.Dequeue () returned 0x4026fd
foo () called

bar () called, x = 21, y = 99
bar () called, x = 21, y = 99
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pfaW17Up5jr09D6H).

Moral: KISS, there are far too many toys in the toybox these days.  Enjoy the weekend people.

Comment: What if wanted to pass an argument to `foo()`?

Comment: I _knew_ you were going to ask me that :)  Updated my post. `[] () { bar (21, 99); }` is a **lambda expression** which serves to capture and encapsulate the parameters to be passed to `bar()` when it is eventually called via (a new overload of) `call_if_function()`.  Welcome to 'modern' C++.  It's new for me too.

Comment: Thank you :)) You've made a child's day come true! This class, is actually part of a library that I'm building.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I enjoyed working through the problem. And thank you for your edit (rushing, rushing) and good luck.

Comment: Oh, nearly forgot.  `std::vector` is not a good choice of container here (because `erase()`, especially on the first element, is expensive).  I would switch to `std::queue` instead, which is designed specifically to do the job. This should only take you a few minutes to do and won't affect any code that uses the class. Check out `std::queue` at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) for details (they generally have good examples there).

Comment: Alright. I'll have a look. Current source can be found at [GitHub](https://www.github.com/Edwin-Pratt/smart-cpp)

Comment: Sorry :'( Stack Overflow... I wanted to ask if it is possible to reverse the vector and use erase like that?

Comment: _Anything_ is possible with STL containers, it's just a matter of choosing the right one.  If this issue is important to you, please ask a new question (you can always link back to this one).  And please ask the _right_ question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

And, since I took the time to research it a bit (mainly because I wanted to learn a bit about it), here is a bit of super-simple SFINAE cobbled together from [the wise ones](https://www.google.com).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// Primary template (required)
template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct X { };

// Specialisation to take a function pointer
template <class T>
struct X <T, typename std::enable_if <std::is_function<T>::value>::type>
{
    X (T func)
    {
        std::cout << "T is a function\n";
        func ();
    }
};

// Partial specialisation for anything else
template<class T>
struct X <T, typename std::enable_if <!std::is_function<T>::value>::type>
{
    X (T x)
    {
        std::cout << "T is not a function (and x is " << x << ")\n";
    }
};

void foo () { std::cout << "foo () called\n"; }

int main ()
{
    X <void ()> x1 (foo);
    X <int> x2 (42);
}
```

Output:

```
T is a function
foo () called
T is not a function (and x is 42)
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MFmTPOiJmetyz4GB).

Powerful stuff, but not the answer to every little problem.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I determine whether a function's parameter type is a function?

You can use the [`std::is_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) to do that.

An implementation like

```
template <class Type, typename Data>
class Queue {
    public:
        Queue (Data& data) {
            if (typeid(Type).name() == int) {
                // Pseodo-code:
                if (std::is_function<data.type>::value) {
                     Enqueue (data);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

won't work though, since the part inside the `if` block scope is seen for other data types by the compiler.

To realize that you'll need to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), and provide different specializations of your `Queue` constructor function using [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: I think adding a simple example of that [SFINAE] to your answer might help the OP.

Comment: And there's `if constexpr`. Welcome back btw.

Comment: @Passer _"And there's if constexpr."_ Hmm, seems I've been hanging around with Delphi too long recently :P

Answer (score -1):

For a SFINAE example:

```
Queue(std::enable_if_t<std::is_function_v<Data>, Data>::type & data)
{
    //data is a function
}

//I'm not sure if the enable_if is needed here, maybe you can just do Data& data
Queue(std::enable_if_t<!std::is_function_v<Data>, Data>::type & data)
{
    //data is not a function
}
```

(You need to include `<type_traits>` to use `std::is_function_v`)

Comment: This is not right. You can't SFINAE on default values for template parameters.

Comment: I should verify it then. Give me a few minutes to fix it.

Comment: This is still all sorts of wrong. You should probably make sure it works in a compiler to start with.

Comment: Yeah true, will do that

Comment: Best book on templates and SFINAE is in my opinion *C++ templates: The complete guide (2nd edition)*