# Passing functions with multiple parameters as a template parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters

### Original question

How can I pass a function **with** or **without** a parameter as a template?

The reason been is that I've updated my *`Queue` Data Structure* as I was told in my other question on how to [determine whether a function parameter is a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112395/determine-whether-function-parameter-is-a-function).

Now, the only problem is that it only accepts functions without parameters. Is there a way I can improve it to accept multiple parameters?

Here's my code:

```cpp
// Necessary includes:
#include <vector>
#include <any>

// If the data is a function:
void call_if_function(void (*function)()) {
    function();
}

// If the data is not a function:
void call_if_function(std::any variable) {
    (void)variable;
}

template <class T>
class Queue {
    // Public members:
    public:
        // Enqueue data:
        void Enqueue(const T& data) {
            vec_.push_back(data);
        }

        // Dequeue data:
        void Dequeue() {
            T holder = vec_.front();

            vec_.erase(vec_.begin());

            call_if_function(holder);
        }

    // Private members:
    private:
        std::vector<T> vec_;
}
```

### Edited question

During continuous tests, I eventually tried using templates. But I'm not sure how to check if a templated variable is existing.

Comment: Just change function signature accordingly `CallIfItIsAFunction(void (*function)(int x), int x) { (*function)(x); }` or make it a template similar to `std::invoke`

Comment: @VTT but won't `int` allow integer types?

Comment: Put whatever types you want instead of `int`.

Comment: @VTT `Queue` is going to be part of a small library called [smart-cpp](https://www.github.com/Edwin-Pratt/smart-cpp), so it **needs** type inference. That is the reason why it is templated.

Comment: This is the second question in a chain where you are askong to do things, and where your example reason why you want to do thats thing seems... questionable.  Please describe what the practical end use you are looking for, as well as the small technical problem getting in the way.  There is every sogn that you are solvimg the wromg problem.  Also known as an X/Y problem.

Comment: Don't get me wrong; this is solvable.  But it reads like someone who wants to (say) stop a car, and instead of asking about using the brakes is asking about attzching a parachute or spikes to dig into the road.  Because they don't know the car has brakes, but thought " a parachute would solve my problem", so they asked a question about installing a parachute.  Sure you can install a parachute, but the real answer is "just use the brakes".

Answer (score 0):

@VTT's comments actually saved me.

```
#include <variant>

typedef std::variant<int, double> any_num;

any_num add(any_num a, any_num b)
{
    return a + b;
}

any_num call_if_function(any_num(*function)(any_num, any_num), any_num a, any_num b)
{
    return function(a, b);
}
```